# Use of being in a sentence

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between following two sentences?

1. Thanks for my sister
2. Thanks for being my sister

I would like to know which one is correct? If both are correct then what is the difference? For me both have same meaning.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us more details of where you found them and the context?

Comment: In (2) you are thanking your sister because you appreciate her. In (1) you are thanking someone else, though it's not clear why.